# Excel 2016 Complex Nested IF

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm working with an Excel sheet with more than 2,000 rows. The image I've attached shows the problem. I've checked the questions on StackOverflow & I don't see anything addressing this situation:

[image: Snapshot that illustrates the situation]

I need a formula to calculate the percentage in column E (E is formatted as a percentage). I can do this by hand logically but it takes upwards of 15 minutes and the report needs to be produced daily. The list comes from SQL Server and I can't get my SQL query to handle this either, nor can I make it work in VBA for Excel.

Logic for Cell E3:

> If C2='house' and C3='house' and C4='house', then '100'
>       If C2='house' and C3='house' and C4='prospect', then 'C3/SUM(C3:C4)'
>       If C2='house' and C3='prospect' and C4='house', then 'C3/SUM(C2:C3)'
>       If C2='house' and C3='prospect' and C4='prospect', then 'C3/SUM(C2:C3)'
>       If C2='prospect' and C3='prospect' and C4='prospect', then '100'
>       If C2='prospect' and C3='house' and C4='house', then, '100'
>       If C2='prospect' and C3='house' and C4='prospect', then 'C3/SUM(C3:C4)'
>       If C2='prospect' and C3='prospect' and C4='house', then '100'

Thank you, in advance, for any assistance!

Comment: How can you sum and divide a string If C3 = House then you cannot `="house"/("house+"house")`

Comment: What have you tried? Did you put that into the Excel formula format? If so, were there any errors? Can you please clarify the problem?

Comment: If you want SQL Server solution, post sample data with desired results. Not just screenshots

Comment: Thanks to all who responded.  I'm new to posting on StackOverflow and am obviously unskilled at writing in an acceptable level of detail and format.

Comment: Thanks, Robin Mackenzie, for editing so this question was legible.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously there was a typo in your question, you meant to calculate with numbers on column `D` not `C`, i.e `D3/Sum(D3:D4)` etc.

You could try to simply write that logic with *nested if's*... But I realize that the rule, which looked like a digital logic exercise, is actually much simpler. In summary the equation should detect the flip from "House" to "Prospect", if any.

Try this formula at `E3` and copy it down:

```
E3:
=D3/(D3+  (D2*(C2="House")*(C3="Prospect"))  +  (D4*(C3="House")*(C4="Prospect")))
```

Comment: Obviously. I was judging the amount the op had invested into their own question.  But for the life of me I would not have come up with this.  This is truly amazing.

Comment: A.S.H., thank you for a simple and elegant solution! This is exactly what I wanted, and, yes, forgive me for typing the wrong column(C instead of D) in my example.